# 'fetch' from router - how to have 'res.status(400).json('Enter failure message here')' be handled as an error in .then .catch?

Tags: json, react-native, server, fetch, response

I have the following code as part of a Button in one of my React Native components. Observe how there is no .catch to handle a possible 'no results' case from server; it is handled with if-statements instead (e.g.: else if (acceptMatchRequestData['status']==='failure') which I was what I'm trying to get away from.

```
                  await acceptMatchRequest(match['matchId'], userId, getUserInfoData[0]['ratings'][matchType])
                  .then(acceptMatchRequestData => {
                    if (acceptMatchRequestData['status']==='success') {
                      setMatchInvites(prevState => {
                        return prevState.filter((observation, i) => observation['matchId'] !== match['matchId'])
                      })
                      setMatchScreenParentState('loading')
                      sendToUserDeviceNotification('matchFound', userId, match['matchedUserId'])
                    } else if (acceptMatchRequestData['status']==='failure') {
                      Alert.alert('', acceptMatchRequestData['message'])
                    }
                  })
```

acceptMatchRequest function code:

```
export async function acceptMatchRequest(matchId, userId, rating) {
  console.log('Attempting to accept match request');

  info = { matchId, userId, rating }

  const firebaseIdToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@firebaseIdToken')
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + firebaseIdToken },
      body: JSON.stringify(info)
  };
  const response = await fetch(ngrokOrLocalhost + '/acceptmatchrequest', requestOptions)
  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}
```

And server code:

```
router.post('/acceptmatchrequest', async (req, res) => {
  const { matchId, userId, rating } = req.body;
    
  const results = await Match.find({ 'usersInfo.userId': userId, 'matchRecords.matchConfirmed': { $nin: [true] } }).limit(5)

  if (results.length===5) {
    res.status(400).json({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'You already have 5 active matches. Please finish a match first before you can accept this match.'})
  } else {
    var filter2 = { '_id': matchId }
    var update2 = { 'isCustomRequest_IsAccepted': true, '$push': { 'usersInfo': { 'userId': userId, 'location': { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [0, 0] }, 'rating': rating } } }
    var response2 = await Match.findOneAndUpdate(filter2, update2, { new: true, sort: { 'matchCreatedTimestamp': 1 } })

    if (response2) {
      // Document was updated
      res.status(200).json({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Match request was accepted successfully'})
    } else {
      console.log('Match request was not accepted successfully');
      res.status(400).json({'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Match request was not accepted successfully'})
    }
  }
})
```